# Choosing the type of battery for a project

Tags: batteries, atmega, servo, lipo, nimh

I am working on a machine which consists of 10 servos, and one microcontroller. The servos need to be on pretty much all the time for about 8 minutes. I am planning on using the ATmega16 to provide the signal to the servos. The servos I am using are the [TGY-S4505B](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__13360__TGY_S4505B_40g_4_8kg_0_10sec_Dual_Bearing_Analog_Servo.html).

So the problem I am having is that there is no specification for the amount of power that servo draws, so I don't know what to design for.

Second, I don't know which type of battery works best for a project like this one. I can choose either NiMh or LiPo (the machine is mobile, so it must have a portable power source). I have the facility to charge both, I just don't know which type is better. The weight of the power source should be < 250g, but this is flexible. Any advice regarding the power setup for my project would be very helpful.

Comment: Are there any weight requirements? Any reason you cannot power servos with line power (is the machine mobile)?

Comment: @JYelton Good questions. The battery pack(s) should be < 250g (this is relatively flexible), and the machine is mobile. I will add this info to the question.

Comment: Turnigy doesn't seem to have a very good [site](http://turnigy.co.uk/), let alone a datasheet for the linked servo. It would be useful to be able to find that unit's electrical characteristics as well as duty cycle. If you already have these servos, you could measure current usage on one to start to get an idea of the project's overall power requirements.

Comment: @JYelton Unfortunately I don't own one. I was expecting an estimate, maybe of max power draw from a typical servo this size so that I could make conservative estimates for my project. I have no clue how much power servos draw at all.

Comment: @JYelton - I really, really doubt that that page is actually an official turnigy site. It looks like a fan-thing, with the added bonus of making a buck selling stuff while looking official. The WHOIS for the site is just some guy in the UK, not a company or anything.

Comment: Turnigy is a direct-from-china brand, really. It's the house-brand of HobbyKing.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can derive some ballpark values from the performance specs of the servo. At full torque (4.8 kg-cm) and speed (0.1s/60°), it's producing about 5W of mechanical work. Taking various inefficiencies into account, each servo can reasonably be expected to draw over 1A of peak current.

It really depends on how much work you're expecting the servos to do over those 8 minutes (collectively, on average). Worst case, you could be looking at 10A full time, which would require a battery capacity of 1.33 A-h per run.

Comment: err, may want to double-check your calculations. These are not 5W servos.

Comment: @helloworld922: Nor are they 1/8W servos. You seem to have missed the fact that the torque is given as kg-cm, not N-cm, which accounts for a factor of 10. You also assumed that that the torque and speed could not be accomplished simultaneously, which accounts for another factor of 4.

Comment: Doh, definitely right about the Newtons part. Yes, it is possible for them to spec max power torque and speed. Seems silly to me, but that doesn't mean it's impossible, and there is no way to tell without further information.

Comment: Thanks! Great response. Curious though about what battery type you would recommend (NiMh or LiPo).

Answer (score 2):

Rushing.
 Not enough data for high quality answer (from anyone).
 2500 mAh NimH is about 30g/battery or about 8 batteries.
LiPo mass and volume energy density is maybe just slightly higher.
 LiPo should be  able to have higher discharge rate and higher charge rate.
 LiPo has safety issues but these are usually not a major factor if done well.

NimH have about 8 x 1.2V x 2.5 Ah = 24 Watt.hour of energy stored. If discharged at 8 minute rate = 8C+ that will drop to say 12-15 Wh.
 8 minutes at 12 Wh = 60/8 x 12 =~~ 90 Watts continuous.
LiPo liable to be substantially better at high C rate for high I specified version.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one of these on hand already I would hook up two multi-meters, one to measure current and the other to measure voltage (ideally you should have a controlled load, too). Calculate the power consumption and scale accordingly.

A quick back-of-the-envelope calculation:

The motor looks likes a standard brushed DC motor.

Relative specs:

Torque: `3.9kg.cm @ 4.8v / 4.8kg.cm @ 6v`

Speed: `0.13sec 60°@ 4.8v / 0.10 60° @ 6v`

The assumption is they listed the stall torque and no-load speed.

Maximum mechanical power from this motor (assuming 6V drive):

\begin{equation}
\frac{47.1 N \cdot cm}{2} \cdot \frac{10.472 rad \cdot sec^{-1}}{2} = 1.21 W
\end{equation}

For 10 of these that would be `12.21W`.

Running at max power for 8 minutes, the minimum battery energy capacity should be `5861J`. Battery capacity isn't normally specified in Joules, so let's do a quick A*hr calculation.

Assuming perfectly efficient motors and 6V drive, we would need `12.21W / 3V = 4.07A` minimum to drive all motors at max power. If you stall all the motors the current consumption is twice of this, or `8.14A`. So over 8 minutes, your minimum battery capacity for stalling all the motors is `1085.3 mA hr`.

Now motors aren't perfectly efficient, and unfortunately they don't list how efficient they are. They could be as bad as single digits or in the 90% range. I would calculate on the cautious side, say 20% (those motors don't exactly scream "efficient" to me). So shoot for a battery capacity of greater than `5.43 A hr`. Of course, this assumes you're fully stalling the motors the full 8 minutes, which if you are you probably have other problems. Depending on the exact use case you can probably get away with a smaller capacity. Don't forget that other circuitry will consume battery power, too.

Comment: Awesome answer. I have to go through it a few more times to make sure I understand your train of thought perfectly, but it makes sense. By the way, do you know which battery type I should go for? (i.e. NiMh or LiPo) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, why are you dividing by two in your first calculations?

Comment: Torque decreases linearly as speed increases, so half no-load speed = half stall torque. Multiply the two together and that's the maximum theoretical mechanical power output of a DC motor. As Dave mentioned the values specified aren't necessarily stall torque and no load speed, even if it is common to do so so you may end up needing 4x the values I calculated.

Comment: Thanks. Though your answer is quite different from Dave's (almost a 4 Ah difference). Odd.

Comment: Cause I assumed 20% motor efficiency and Dave assumed 100%. Also, Dave assumed 4x mechanical power to what I had. Who is right (if either) really depends on better motor specs which aren't available on the link. This is why good spec sheets are vital for engineering work.

Comment: Oh yes, I see now. Alright, well I guess I will only find out when I have the parts on hand.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a rough estimate of how much battery you need regardless of the servos by considering how much mechanical [work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_%28physics%29) you need to do, and then guessing at the efficiency of converting electrical energy to work (50% is reasonable, absent any measurements). Work equals force times distance:

\$ W = Fd \$

If force is in newtons and distance is in meters, then work will be in joules, a unit of energy. You can also consider the maximum mechanical [power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_%28physics%29) required, which is the product of force and velocity:

\$ P = Fv \$

If force is in newtons and velocity is in meters per second, then power is in watts, just like electrical systems. Again add a fudge factor for inefficiency in the electrical <-> mechanical conversion.

You can get the maximum power a battery can deliver by multiplying its nominal voltage by its maximum rated current:

\$ P = IE \$

This gives you a rough idea of the current your battery must supply, which can give you an idea of the battery chemistry you need. It also tells you that if you decrease the force or velocity of your servos, you need less battery current.

Determining the energy extractable from a battery is a little harder since the battery's internal losses will depend on the manner in which the energy is extracted. A simplifying assumption is that you can get the rated amount of electrical charge (mAh) at the battery's nominal voltage. A 1000 mAh battery could ideally supply 1A for one hour at the nominal voltage. We have current and voltage to get power, and we have time (one hour) to get energy. Let's assume a nominal voltage of 12V for example:

\$ 1000mAh \cdot 12V \dfrac {3660s}{1h} \dfrac{1}{1000m} \$

cancel units:

\$ 1000A \cdot 12V \dfrac {3660s}{1} \dfrac{1}{1000} = 1000A \cdot 12V \cdot 3.660s \$

An amp-volt is a watt, and a watt-second is a joule, so we can say:

\$ 1000A \cdot 12V \cdot 3.660s \approx 44 kJ\$

Or more generally:

\$ Q_{mAh} \cdot V_{bat} \cdot 3.66 = E \$

This is true to the extent that the battery's voltage is \$V_{bat}\$. Of course you know the voltage sags with high current and decreases as it discharges, and also battery manufacturers like to specify capacity well past the point considered "dead" for most applications, so introduce an appropriate fudge-factor: maybe half the rated mAh unless you can find more detailed information in the battery datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

Although we have lots of calculations, it seems that nobody mentioned which battery type to actually use.

My "blanket" solution would be to always go for LiPo unless you actually have the NiMHs available or are really afraid that LiPo is going to explode or start burning. Also LiPos have much higher energy density and would be much easier to fit into the 250 g limit.

There are 6 Ah LiPo batteries commonly available for toy cars and helicopters which can sustain high discharge currents. I however see two problems here: First is voltage and second is mass.

For 6 V operation, you'll probably want at least "2S' batteries. They have two cells connected in series and their nominal voltage, if I remember correctly, is 7.4 V. Maximum voltage is 8.4 V, but it will drop quickly. This may require use of a buck regulator to power servo motors. I don't really see a way to use a single cell, since its full voltage of 4.2 V would be too small.

The second problem is mass. From what I can see, mass for batteries of capacity near 6 Ah is in the 400 g to 600g range. The 2S batteries seem closer to the 400 g margin while 3 S batteries are usually over 500 g. At around 3 Ah to 4 Ah, there are available batteries with mass of around 300 g, so they might be a suitable compromise if experimentation shows that the 6 Ah value is overkill.

For the end one more recommendation: Make sure to get battery with a "balance" plug. Such connector provides individual access to each cell and makes correct charging and easy inspection to each cell possible. Some cheaper batteries may not have such connector, so do avoid them.

Comment: Thanks for actually answering an essential part of my question. I think I will go with LiPo batteries. I already have some, as well as a great balance charger (Accucel 6). The thing I am wondering is why you mentioned I need 6 Ah. That seems a bit much for 10 servos running for 8 minutes.

Comment: @capcom Well helloworld922 mentions 5.43 Ah for size, so I rounded it up a bit to net common size.