# How do I calculate required voltage and current for multiple servos?

Tags: voltage, batteries, current, battery-operated, servo

I'm looking to power 3 [servos](https://www.amazon.co.uk/ANNIMOS-Digital-Waterproof-Crawler-Control/dp/B07GK1G5FV/ref=asc_df_B07GK1G5FV/?tag=googshopuk-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=309757378209&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=13568895581870017911&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9045958&hvtargid=pla-524714589526&psc=1) and control them with an Arduino Uno.

Could someone please explain to me, not just specifically for this, how I can work out how much voltage and current I need to power several motors at maximum power? I've heard that it doesn't matter how high of a current I supply as the motors will only draw what it needs from the battery. Is this true? If so how do I know the minimum current I must supply? As for the voltage, I've heard things like for a 6V motor you can use 6V to power up to 4 motors. If this is true, why is 4 the cutoff? And does that mean I need 6.8V for these?

Also how do I choose which type of battery to go for? This needs to be portable so I can't have mains connections, so how do I choose between the AA type of batteries, LiPo or Nickel, etc..?

Sorry for the basic questions, just trying to build up from the foundations.

Comment: Look at the answer to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/76544/choosing-the-right-batteries

Comment: Also look at the answers to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/58143/choosing-the-type-of-battery-for-a-project

Comment: You should review [this fundamental question about voltage and current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/34745/2028); it should clear up a few things.

Answer (score 1):

The specs for the servo indicate about 2A at stall, with a supply voltage of 5 to 6.8V.  You can use any voltage in that range regardless of the number of servos you’re using.  If all of the servos could operate at the same time then you’ll need a current capability of 2A per servo, so 8A for 4 servos (plus a little bit for the Arduino).  You could use 5 NiMH cells giving about 6V, but 8A is quite a bit for AA cells.  18650 lithium cells have a much higher current capability (some up to 40A) but the voltage isn’t ideal to use directly so you’d need a DC-DC converter.  Unless you need maximum servo torque you might stick to 5V which can power the Arduino directly.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. So since I need 3 of these servos, 4x AA (Ni/MH) batteries wont suffice as they can't output 6 Amperes at once?

Comment: 4 AA cells will give you 4.8V which may be ok.  6A is a tall order from AAs, but if the servos won’t be loaded to stall you might be ok.  If necessary you could parallel another 4 cells.